# Python - Writing data to .cfg files in multiple lines

Tags: python, file

Let's say we have a quote

> Manners Maketh Man

and we fill 3 variables with the values `Manners` `Maketh` `Man` respectively. Now I also have a `quote.cfg` file :

```
[quotes]
myquote = None
```

I want to store the 3 variables in `[quotes]` section and in the variable `myquote`. But the problem is how do I store it in 3 different lines. I can store it in a single line by [Python 2.7] :

```
import ConfigParser as cfg

file = 'quote.cfg'

config = cfg.ConfigParser()
config.read(file)

def set_config(sec, attr, value):
    config.set(sec, attr, value)
    with open(file, 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
a = "Manners"
b = "Maketh"
c = "Man"
set_config('quotes','myquote',a+" "+b+" "+c)
print config.get('quotes','myquote')
```

which would look like :

```
[quotes]
myquote = Manners Maketh Man
```

but I want it to store like:

```
[quotes]
myquote = Manners
          Maketh
          Man
```

Comment: Try: `set_config('quotes', 'myquote', '\n'.join([a, b, c]))`

Comment: Replace ```" "``` with ```"\n"```

Comment: Question remains - why?

Comment: @Jan I am actually preparing a Telegram bot, where I need to send data from a cfg file in multiple lines.. so

Comment: and if you need to display your data as HTML, will you save HTML to .cfg as well?

Comment: @lenik Why would I? I was pretty happy using .cfg files, so I just want a solution to my problem. Not everything to be converted into .cfg